# How to insert data from one Sqlite database to another using SQL query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, dbeaver

I'm running a Minecraft server and trying to move datas from the plugin AuthMe to limboAuth. Now I have the authme.db file storing player information. Based on the introduction on the [limboAuth site](https://forums.papermc.io/threads/limboauth-auth-system-built-in-virtual-server-limbo.330/), I should run the SQL script

`INSERT INTO limbo.AUTH SELECT realname, username, COALESCE(password, ""), COALESCE(ip, ""), COALESCE(totp, ""), regdate, "", "", NULL, NULL, NULL FROM authme.table WHERE username IS NOT NULL`

I tried to run this script with DBeaver (though the scripts seems only run on one file but not globally). Anyway, I can't execuate it since I don't have the database limbo.db and table limbo.AUTH.

`[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: limbo.AUTH)`

I created a file limbo.db but can't generate a empty table limbo.AUTH. I think I'm understanding the instruction wrongly but not sure what should I do. Also, how can I open two database at the same time. I see people are using ATTACH but I don't think it works in the DBeaver.

Comment: See https://sqlite.org/lang_attach.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see people are using ATTACH but I don't think it works in the DBeaver.

It does (but note the use of the full path, not just the database name)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, also seems I need to adjust the limbo.AUTH to AUTH since I'm running the script within that .db file.

Comment: Will add the like later...I don't have enough reputation yet